IMPORTRANGE: how to Pivot, Group, and Aggregate by two types of animals
I have an IMPORTRANGE(...) that yields the following table:



Adoption Date
Take-Home Date
Name
Dogs
Puppies
Cats
Kittens
Chickens
Chicks
...




01/25/2023
01/26/2023
Cody
3
0
2
1
30
5
...


02/24/2024
02/29/2024
Rob
0
2
0
4
0
0
...


01/29/2024
01/29/2024
Rob
1
0
2
4
2
10
...


01/29/2024
01/29/2024
Rob
2
1
0
1
5
3
...


...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...



I would like to wrap that function in something like a QUERY() with a GROUPBY or a PIVOT() or some combination of TRANSPOSE() and SUM() to yield the following result:



Adoption Date
Take-Home Date
Name
Animal
# Adults
# Young




01/25/2023
01/26/2023
Cody
Canine
3
0


01/25/2023
01/26/2023
Cody
Feline
2
1


01/25/2023
01/26/2023
Cody
Bird
30
5


02/24/2024
02/29/2024
Rob
Canine
0
2


02/24/2024
02/29/2024
Rob
Feline
0
4


01/29/2024
01/29/2024
Rob
Canine
3
1


01/29/2024
01/29/2024
Rob
Feline
2
5


01/29/2024
01/29/2024
Rob
Bird
7
13


...
...
...
...
...
...



Note that there is no row for Rob's Birds, since those values are all zero.
In essence, I need to take all unique combinations of Adoption Date, Take-Home Date, Name, and (pivoted) animal species, and aggregate the sum of adults and the sum of young.  I'm sure this is possible in one formula, but can't wrap my mind around the grouping, aggregation, and pivot as a function of a query SQL statement.  Thanks for any help.

@player0 11 species and an "other" category.

@player0 I can setup a lookup, but also young animal will always follow adult animal, so I could use Dogs, Cats, Chickens, instead of Canine, Feline, Bird.


Here's one approach you may test out:
=let(Σ,A2:D, Λ,lambda(x,wrapcols(x,rows(Σ),x)),
     query(vstack({Σ,Λ("Canine"),E2:F},
                  {Σ,Λ("Feline"),G2:H},
                  {Σ,Λ("Bird"),  I2:J}),
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,sum(Col6),sum(Col7) where Col6>0 OR Col7>0 group by Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5 label sum(Col6) '',sum(Col7) ''"))



If you need to add, let's say, one more species (horse, baby horse) in columns K,L; then the total range (assigned to shortcut Σ) would be A2:L && within the vstack you need to add the additional condition as such {Σ,Λ("Equine"),K2:L}
Last Name is added as Column_D here for representation


This formula version embeds & processes your importrange data directly.
=let(Σ,importrange("Sheet_ID","data!A2:J"), Γ,choosecols(Σ,1,2,3,4), Λ,lambda(x,wrapcols(x,rows(Σ),x)),
     query(vstack({Γ,Λ("Canine"),choosecols(Σ,5,6)},
                  {Γ,Λ("Feline"),choosecols(Σ,7,8)},
                  {Γ,Λ("Bird"),  choosecols(Σ,9,10)}),
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,sum(Col6),sum(Col7) where Col6>0 OR Col7>0 group by Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5 label sum(Col6) '',sum(Col7) ''"))



try:
={A1:C1, "Animal", "# Adults", "# Young";
 QUERY(QUERY(INDEX(LET(b, D2:INDEX(I:I, MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>""))), a, OFFSET(b,,-3,,3), w, R:S,
 c, TOCOL(FILTER(b, MOD(COLUMN(b)-1, 2)),,1), 
 d, TOCOL(FILTER(b, MOD(COLUMN(b), 2)),,1), 
 e, IFNA(VLOOKUP(TOCOL(FILTER(IF(b="",,OFFSET(b,-1,,1,)), MOD(COLUMN(b)-1, 2)),,1), w, 2, )),
 f, LAMBDA(x, REDUCE(x, SEQUENCE((COLUMNS(b)/2)-1), LAMBDA(a, b, IF(b, {a; x}))))(a), {f, e, c, d})), 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,sum(Col5),sum(Col6) group by Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4", ), 
 "where Col5>0 or Col6>0", )}



you will need to change I:I to reflect last column
range with animals ofc needs to have an even number of columns
change R:S to reflect your lookup table
without lookup table it would be:



feeding it directly with IMPORTRANGE would be:



where ofc Sheet18!D2:I5 is:



update
it depends where that column with last name is exactly. for example if it is here:

formula would change like this:
={"Adoption Date", "Take-Home Date", "Name", "LAST NAME", "Animal", "# Adults", "# Young";
 QUERY(QUERY(INDEX(LET(b, IMPORTRANGE("1sPiWXvVIIuNdUEl04Ku8zZs0zL3HYnTFXwV2C67Ex5k", "Sheet18!E2:J5"), a, OFFSET(b,,-4,,4), w, R:S,
 c, TOCOL(FILTER(b, MOD(COLUMN(b), 2)),,1), 
 d, TOCOL(FILTER(b, MOD(COLUMN(b)-1, 2)),,1), 
 e, IFNA(VLOOKUP(TOCOL(FILTER(IF(b="",,OFFSET(b,-1,,1,)), MOD(COLUMN(b), 2)),,1), w, 2, )),
 f, LAMBDA(x, REDUCE(x, SEQUENCE((COLUMNS(b)/2)-1), LAMBDA(a, b, IF(b, {a; x}))))(a), {f, e, c, d})), 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,sum(Col6),sum(Col7) group by Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5", ), 
 "where Col6>0 or Col7>0", )}



This works exactly as I requested.  Turns out that I need to include a last name column, and I've been trying to adapt your formula, but having some trouble.  Have a quick moment to give a clue ?
